# Keep a shadow copy of a table while retaining records removed from the original

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is probably laughably easy for an SQL expert, but SQL (although I can use it) is not really my thing.

I've got a table in a DB. (Let's call it COMPUTERS)
About 10.000 rows. 25 columns. 1 unique key: Column ASSETS.

Occasionally an external program will delete 1 or more of the rows, but isn't supposed to do that, because we still need to know some info from those rows before we can really delete the items.

We can't control the behavior of the external application so we came up with a different idea:

We want to create a second identical table (COMPUTERS_BACKUP) and initially fill this with a one-on-one copy of COMPUTERS.
After that, once a day copy new records from COMPUTERS to COMPUTERS_BACKUP and update those records in COMPUTERS_BACKUP where the original in COMPUTERS has changed (ASSETS column will never change).

That way we keep the last state of a record deleted from COMPUTERS.

Can someone supply the code for a stored procedure that can be scheduled to run once a day? I can probably figure this out myself, but it would take me several hours or so and I'm very pressed for time.

Comment: Why don't you just add a `DELETE` trigger to log the deleted rows? You might be able to filter on `APP_NAME()` to just log ones deleted by the problematic application.

Comment: Do ever delete rows from that table in your application?

Comment: @MartinSmith That was my first instinct too, but... I didn't tell the hole story: The table is actually truncated and then re-filled by the external application. Stupid design, but we've got to live with it.

Comment: @peterm Yes. The application has a cleanup function for that. We can change that to cleanup the backup table too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just create a trigger for insert computers table

```
CREATE TRIGGER newComputer
ON [Computers]
AFTER INSERT
Begin

INSERT INTO COMPUTERS_BACKUP
  SELECT * FROM Inserted

End
```

It'll work when you insert new computer to computers table and it'll also insert the record to bakcup table

When you update computers you could change computers backup too with update trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER newComputer
ON [Computers]
AFTER UPDATE
Begin
//can access before updating the record through SELECT * FROM Deleted
//can access after updating the record through SELECT * FROM Inserted
UPDATE Computers_BACKUP SET
 (attributes) = inserted.(attribute)
WHERE id = inserted.id

End
```

At the end I guess you don't want to delete the backup when original record is deleted from computers table. You can chech more examples from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa258254%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) using triggers.

When a record removed from computers table

```
CREATE TRIGGER computerDeleted ON [Computers] AFTER DELETE
Begin

INSERT INTO Computers_BACKUP
  SELECT * FROM Deleted

End
```

Comment: It should be `FOR DELETE` trigger, not `Update`

Comment: of course, if you'd like to keep just deleted records you'll have to write only deleted trigger to insert backup table. But in your question, you've written to keep the whole table copy that might cause not to insert the deleted record when you try to insert that already exists. I may misunderstood. I'll update my answer

Comment: Then there should be 3 triggers Insert, Update, and Delete, with each change timestapmed.

Comment: Yes, if you'd like to track the whole changes of computers table you should have insert, update and delete triggers.

Comment: I like this. As the computers table get's truncated and then rebuild by a massive insert from another table a delete trigger won't help me, but I had not though about abusing the insert and update triggers like this. (I realize the insert trigger would cause a big performance hit on a bulk-insert, but CPU is cheap. I can just assign more power to the VM on which the SQL server runs.)

Comment: I don't think it cause big performance issues unless massive bulk insertions which I always don't have :) and sometimes you have to ignore performance due to keep history of significant data.

Comment: I implemented the insert and update triggers and it works like a charm. Performance hit on bulk insert is barely noticeable. (I notice, but other users think it is just another bit of typical lag caused by busy LAN or overactive virusscanner.)

Answer (score 1):

IMHO a possible solution, if you never delete records (only update) from that table in your application,  can be to introduce an `INSTEAD OF DELETE` trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER tg_computers_delete ON computers
INSTEAD OF DELETE AS
DELETE computers WHERE 1=2;
```

It will prevent the deletion of the records.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/58b63/1)** demo.

Answer (score 1):

Besides creating triggers, you may look into enabling [Change Data Capture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933994%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), which is  available in SQL Server Enterprise Edition. It may be an overshot, but it should be mentioned and you may find it useful for other tables and objects.

Answer (score 0):

A trigger for `Before Delete` event can help you to guard this table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER backup_row_before_delete ON COMPUTERS_Table FOR Delete
as 
    INSERT INTO Computers_Backup
    SELECT deleted.* from deleted
```

You can change `deleted.*` for `deleted.col1, deleted.col2` if you want to keep certain columns only.

Comment: This isn't SQL Server syntax I'm afraid :(

Comment: That is not valid SQL Server syntax. `CREATE TRIGGER backup_row_before_delete ON COMPUTERS_Table FOR DELETE AS INSERT INTO Computers_Backup SELECT * FROM DELETED;`

Comment: I am no SQL guru, but I doubt that would trigger on a truncate table. See above.

Answer (score 0):

> will delete 1 or more of the rows, but isn't supposed to do that

Then you have permission and integrity issues.

You can most certainly use a trigger to record deletions (and updates of course) but I would not recommend you use it purely to keep a copy of stuff you didn't want deleted in the first place!

Remove delete permissions if you have to or beef up your data integrity if you can.  Without your schema it's hard to tell exactly how though.

Finally, use your (INSTEAD OF) trigger to check whatever conditions you need to prevent the delete  when appropriate.

Comment: See my comment to MartinSmith. It's not a permission/integrity thing. We get a copy of the original table and our app uses it for different purposes. It's just that our use of the data has slightly different requirements. Actually the originating app's behavior changed a few weeks ago. Our use of the data didn't. The dependency on this externally supplied data is a stupid design mistake made several years ago. Now I'm trying to deal with the consequences.